# MS Access - Select records by rows in a table which does not have unique column

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have two non primary key columns as Field1 and Field2 & the first few records in the table are sometimes not required for executuion. One record in the table displays the text 'Code','TotalValue' in field1 and field2 respectively, and I want all the records to be displayed which are available next to this record. How could I write the query to select the records by rows when I don't have unique values in a column.

Eg:

```
Field1  Field2
Billing Transactional File  bt_billing_transactional_20140626_00000806.dat
Number of Records   44
Number of Accounts  8


Code    Total Value
OR20111534  -624989
OR20111072  -485300
OR20111053  -8333
OR20111063  -267828
```

I want all the four records from the above table which are displayed next to record 'Code','TotalValue'. And the row in which the text TotalValue displayed is not static (it can be in 6th or 7th row). If I select the particular records, I can move these into the new table easily.
Note: It wont help even though if I have the unique column. Because the row order may change when order by a column

Thanks

Comment: What have you managed to get so far?

Comment: try this: create a query based on a table which links to your file, that goes something like:
    SELECT * FROM tbl.dat WHERE Field1 LIKE "OR*"

Comment: The Codes doesn't always starts with 'OR', so it's not possible. Is it possible to get all the records displayed under 'Code    Total Value'

Comment: So what comes to mind is:  how can you always have that order of rows you show in the example? If there is no chance to ORDER BY something, what is making you have that result? Is it always as such, without any ORDER BY?  Is that guaranteed?